# renaming code behind class in VS2010, does not change inherits attribute in .aspx form

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

when using auto-rename functionality of vs2010 for renaming a code behind class, this does not change automatically the inherits attribute in the in the .aspx form? at least not in vs2010).

Example: if you rename "Error" class to "ErrorLs" this would lead to errors not caught at compile time, due to that Inherits attribute in page tag was not automatically changed.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Error.aspx.cs" Inherits="ABC.Error" %>
```

The Error.aspx.cs after renaming Error class:

```
namespace ABC
{
    public partial class ErrorLs : Page
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Since this a common task performed by using VS IDE, does anybody knows the reason why is not by default set to change the Inherits attribute either, I am expecting too much :)?**

here I found a link with the same question but no answer from Microsoft Team:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/664505/renaming-partial-classes-via-refactor-rename-should-change-inherits-directive

Comment: Yes you are expecting too much. :-) On a serious note...this is just one of the those things in VS that you unfortunately have to do manually. If there is a workaround, I would like to know.

Comment: heyyy Expecting too much ;) You manually need to change them.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change inherits attribute manually unfortunately.

Comment: This is the only thing that has to be change manually in VS 2010 !
OR
You create the file with correct name, everytime, at the folder you wish.